# C# replace part of string but only exact matches possible?

Tags: c#

I have a `string beginString = "apple|fruitsapple|turnip";`

What I want to do is replace just apple with mango, not fruitsapple.

`string fixedString = beginString.Replace("apple","mango");` This doesn't work because it replaces both apple and fruitsapple.

Any ideas?

Comment: the string has always this format? (words separated by `|`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variation on other answers in LINQ style:

```
string fixedString = string.Join("|",
                                 beginString
                                    .Split('|')
                                    .Select(s => s != "apple" ? s : "mango"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
beginString =  "|" + beginString + "|";
fixedString = beginString.Replace("|apple|","|mango|");
```

Comment: In this example that would work, however, this really isn't dynamic enough +1 though

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done in the way you have said since it will consider the entire string to be a string. You can do the split by | as you have used or else have the strings in a list and use equals and then replace it.

```
String[] words = beginString.Split("|");
```

now do the replace on words. works for any scenario.

Comment: @Dumb is not actually dumb. He's right. Split on the string then iterate through to find your exact match then replace. What do you think these other hidden methods are doing? There is no magic, its just hidden from you to look like less code.

Comment: use split for any character as the split. even you can have splitting delimitters in an array and use it on the string. would give you more leverage if you are not sure what would be the delimitter( even if there are more than 1 is what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can get. Was gonna suggest regular expression, but that won't always work as you want. You have to split the string first and then remake it.

```
string searchString = "apple";
string newString = "mango";

string beginString = "apple|fruitsapple|turnip";

string[] array = beginString.Split('|');
foreach (var item in array)
{
    if (item == searchString)
        item.Replace(searchString, newString);
}

string recreated = "";
new List<string>(array).ForEach(e => recreated += e + "|");
recreated.TrimEnd('|');
```

Comment: You can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) for assembling the string back.

Comment: Mind however that [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) doesn't replace the substring in-place, but rather returns a new string, so the `foreach` loop seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
string newstr = Regex.Replace("apple|fruitsapple|turnip", @"\bapple\b", "mango");
```